# How to prevent current user from rating himself using Django model constraints

Tags: django

So I have a user model and each user should be able to rate other users but shouldn't be able to rate themselves.

Model for rating is

```
#Rating field in User model

ratings = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Rating',
                                       symmetrical=False,
                                       related_name='rated_by')

#Rating model
class Rating(models.Model):
rating = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_rating])
from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="from_people", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="to_people", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Is there a way I can make this functionality? I was thinking django model constraints will work but I do not know how to go about it. How do I filter a request to grab the specific user to prevent them from rating themselves?

I tried:

```
class Rating(models.Model):
rating = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_rating])
from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="from_people", 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="to_people", 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        CheckConstraint(
            check = Q(from_user != User, 
            to_user != User),
            name = 'check_user',
        )
    ]
```

but I get a `Metacheck = Q(from_user != User, NameError: name 'from_user' is not defined` as an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a database level check constraint to your model that will prevent the Rating model from having a record with the from_user and to_user the same.

```
from django.db.models import Q, F, CheckConstraint
class Rating(models.Model):
    rating = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_rating])
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="from_people", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="to_people", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(check=~Q(from_user=F('to_user')), name='no_self_rating')
        ]
```

[Django docs constraint reference.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/)

The above adds the constraint at the database level, but does not do any form validation.

You also ask

> How do I filter a request to grab the specific user to prevent them from rating themselves?

It's not clear what you mean here. The request object passed to the view function has a user attribute that is the user using the application. I'm not sure what your view looks like but:

```
def my_view(request):
    request.user  # This is the user making the action
    ... # Other view code
    return HttpResponse(...)
```

You can pass request.user to a form and validate the user is not rating themselves.

Comment: I get this error `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: check constraint "users_cannot_rate_themselves" of relation "users_rating" is violated by some row` when I migrate...

Comment: Fixed this by deleting other migration files and running `py manage.py makemigrations` and `migrate` again.

Comment: If the existing data in the database violates the check constraint you are adding, the migration fails. You have to make sure your data matches the constraint before you can add it.

Comment: Seems I can still add the same user for both fields, `to_user` and `from_user` when using Django admin.

Comment: Then you haven't applied the change to your database. If I add a Rating model just like above to a project and migrate the database I see a check constraint in the database and attempting to insert data into the rating table with from_user = to_user results in a database error. Make sure the migration has a migrations.AddConstraint in it and the migration has been applied.

Answer (score 0):

A negative CheckConstraint should do what you want.

```
from django.db import models


class Rating(models.Model):
    rating = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_rating])
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="from_people", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="to_people", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=~models.Q(from_user=models.F('to_user')),
                name='users_cannot_rate_themselves'
            ),
        ]
```

Comment: Wow thanks. Any link to learn this from the django docs? Can't seem to find it. Negative constraint, especially.